# autoconf: how do I substitute the library prefix?

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, gnulib

[CLISP](http://clisp.org)'s [interface](http://clisp.org/impnotes/pari.html) to [PARI](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) is configured with the [`configure.in`](https://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/modules/pari/configure.in) containing [`AC_LIB_LINKFLAGS([pari])`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Searching-for-Libraries.html) from [`lib-link.m4`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/m4/lib-link.m4).

The build process also requires the `Makefile` to know where the `datadir` of `PARI` is located. To this end, [`Makefile.in`](https://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/modules/pari/Makefile.in) has

```
prefix = @LIBPARI_PREFIX@
DATADIR = @datadir@
```

and expects to find `$(DATADIR)/pari/pari.desc` (normally
`/usr/share/pari/pari.desc` or `/usr/local/share/pari/pari.desc`).

This seems to work on Mac OS X where `PARI` is installed by [homebrew](https://brew.sh) in `/usr/local` (and `LIBPARI_PREFIX=/usr/local`), but not on Ubuntu, where `PARI` is in `/usr`, and `LIBPARI_PREFIX` is *empty*.

**How do I insert the location of the `PARI`'s `datadir` into the `Makefile`?**

PS. I also asked this on the [autoconf mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/autoconf/2018-01/msg00001.html).

PPS. In response to @BrunoHaible's suggestion, here is the meager attempt at debugging on Linux (where `LIBPARI_PREFIX` is *empty*).

```
$ bash -x configure 2>&1 | grep found_dir
+ found_dir=
+ eval ac_val=$found_dir
+ eval ac_val=$found_dir
```

Comment: I guess you're talking about the `AC_LIB_LINKFLAGS` macro from gnulib (there is no such macro packaged with Autoconf itself), and I have updated the tags correspondingly.  If you mean a different macro then please clarify and update the tags.

Comment: Supposing that you do mean the macro from gnulib, [it's docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Searching-for-Libraries.html) don't say anything about setting a `*_PREFIX` variable.  From where, then, does that come?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: the generated `configure` has `LIBPARI_PREFIX` in `ac_subst_vars` so I hoped that it would work...

Comment: I see that `configure` indeed does contain that variable, and I think `AC_LIB_LINKFLAGS` must indeed be responsible for it, but that does not change the fact that it is not documented.  But I guess that's moot because it doesn't adequately serve your purpose anyway.

Comment: More generally then, do I understand correctly that you intend to locate PARI's data directory by assuming its location to be related to that of the library's through use of a common path prefix and conventional path suffix?  Are you satisfied that that is sufficient?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I think you are implying that I should use something like `dirname(path-to-pari.so)/../share/pari/pari.desc`. This is clearly suboptimal (because pari might have been installed with a non-standard `--datadir` flag), but, I guess, it will work in most cases.

Comment: I'm not implying anything -- I'm just trying to interpret your question.  What I described is what the code you've presented appears to be trying to do.  It sounds like you're *not* satisfied with that.

Comment: Your expectation looks right, because the documentation of the macro says:
`dnl Sets and AC_SUBSTs the LIB${NAME}_PREFIX variable to nonempty if libname
dnl was found in ${LIB${NAME}_PREFIX}/$acl_libdirstem.
`

Comment: The code of AC_LIB_LINKFLAGS_BODY is meant to optimize the special cases `/usr` and `/usr/local` only regarding the LIBPARI and LTLIBPARI variables (which are used for linking, without libtool vs. with libtool). The code that computes LIBPARI_PREFIX should not be affected by this optimization.

Comment: Therefore, you need to debug this macro yourself: Run the `configure` script with "bash -x configure" and inspect the output, paying special attention to the variable `found_dir`. Optionally, insert special debugging statement into lib-link.m4 and regenerate the `configure` script with them.

Comment: @BrunoHaible: my apologies, the please see edit. My code works on MacOSX but not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `$(prefix)` in an unintended way.  In an Autotools-based build system, the `$(prefix)` represents a prefix to the *target* installation location of the software you're building.  By setting it in your `Makefile.in`, you are overriding the prefix that `configure` will try to assign.  However, since you appear not to have any installation targets anyway, at least at that level, that's probably more an issue of poor form than a cause for malfunction.

> **How do I insert the location of the PARI's datadir into the Makefile?**

I'd recommend computing or discovering the needed directory in your configure script, and exporting it to the generated Makefile via its own output variable.  Let's take the second part first, since it's simple.  In **`configure.in`**, having in some manner located the wanted data directory and assigned it to a variable

```
DATADIR=...
```

, you would make an output variable of that via the `AC_SUBST` macro:

```
AC_SUBST([DATADIR])
```

Since you are using only Autoconf, not Automake, you would then manually receive that into your Makefile by changing the assignment in your **`Makefile.in`**:

```
DATDIR = @DATADIR@
```

---

Now, as for locating the data directory in the first place, you have to know what you're trying to implement before you can implement it.  From your question and followup comments, it seems to me that you want this:

1. Use a data directory explicitly specified by the user if there is one.  Otherwise,
2. look for a data directory relative to the location of the shared library.  If it's not found there then
3. (optional) look under the `prefix` specified to `configure`, or specifically in the specified datadir (both of which may come from the top-level `configure`).  Finally, if it still has not been found then
4. look in some standard locations.

To create a `configure` option by which the user can specify a custom data directory, you would probably use the `AC_ARG_WITH` macro, maybe like this:

```
AC_ARG_WITH([pari-datadir], [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-pari-datadir],
    [explicitly specifies the PARI data directory])],
  [], [with_pari_datadir=''])
```

Thanks to @BrunoHaible, we see that although the Gnulib manual does not document it, the macro's internal documentation specifies that if `AC_LIB_LINKFLAGS` locates libpari then it will set `LIBPARI_PREFIX` to the library directory prefix.  You find that that does work when the `--with-libpari` option is used to give it an alternative location to search, so I suggest working with that.  You certainly can try to debug `AC_LIB_LINKFLAGS` to make it set `LIBPARI_PREFIX` in all cases in which the lib is found, but if you don't want to go to that effort then you can work around it (see below).

Although the default or specified installation prefix is accessible in `configure` as `$prefix`, I would suggest instead going to the specified `$datadir`.  That is slightly tricky, however, because by default it refers to the prefix indirectly.  Thus, you might do this:

```
eval "datadir_expanded=${datadir}"
```

Finally, you might hardcode a set of prefixes such as `/usr` and `/usr/local`.

---

Following on from all the foregoing, then, your `configure.in` might do something like this:

```
DATADIR=
for d in \
    ${with_pari_datadir} \
    ${LIBPARI_PREFIX:+${LIBPARI_PREFIX}/share/pari} \
    ${datadir_expanded}/pari \
    /usr/local/share/pari \
    /usr/share/pari
do
  AS_IF([test -r "$[]d/pari.desc"], [DATADIR="$[]d"; break])
done

AS_IF([test x = "x$DATADIR"], [AC_MSG_ERROR(["Could not identify PARI data directory"])])
AC_SUBST([DATADIR])
```

Comment: thanks! why should I use `AS_IF` instead of `if`? Is `if` _really_ unportable?!

Comment: @sds, it's mostly a question of style, but `AS_IF` does provide for ensuring that any macros required by its arguments are expanded first (i.e. outside the scope of the resulting conditional).  My practice is to use M4sh macros such as `AS_IF` instead of raw shell syntax when in fact such macros exist.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of guessing the location of `datadir`, why don't you ask PARI/GP where its `datadir` is located? Namely,

```
$ echo "default(datadir)" | gp -qf
"/usr/share/pari"
```

does the trick.